# How can I pass args in bash that is calling a python script

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash that calls a python script with optional command line args as

`python my_python_script.py "$@"`

My python script uses `argparse` to parse args.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--max_num', type=int, default=-1, help='To be used only if ran in dry run mode')
parser.add_argument('--dry_run', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

However, the problem with about is that it adds `max_num` arg only if `dry_run` arg is passed. How can I make it independent and both args can be passed irrespective of each other.

Comment: Before this block, can you please `print(sys.argv)`?

Comment: At my machine(ubuntu18), it seems work fine.